# Trying to put the arrow a little bigger and to the left of my form option select

Tags: html, css

I have a form with a option select and Im having one issue on formatting.

Im having my arrow on the right of my option very small and much leaning to the right.

Do you know how I can push this arrow to left and put it a little bigger, without take of my border of 5px?

[image]

**This is my html:**

```
<div class="posts">
<form name="editpost" class="formfull" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<label class="label">
  <select name="categories">
       <option value="">Select one category:</option>
       <option value="1">History</option>
       <option value="2">Maths</option>
   </select>
</label>
</form>
</div>
```

**This is my css:**

```
.posts .formfull .label select{min-width:250px; padding:10px; border:5px solid #CCC; font-size:18px;}
```

My fiddle with demonstration of what Im having:

http://jsfiddle.net/g7f9R/1/

Comment: you should customize the select element with some fake drop down button. The default arrow can only be enlarged by increasing the size of the `select` (which is affected by `font-size`)

Comment: Thank you! Im trying to do that but Im having my default icon in front of my image icon. Do you know How I can fix this? This is what im having: http://jsfiddle.net/g7f9R/2/

Comment: Changing the look of `select` and considering browser-compatibility is not easy. Why don't you use javascript solutions to change the UI of the select elements, like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) or jQuery UI?

Comment: here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/g7f9R/3/ However `pointer-events:none` is not widely supported (some old versions of IE and currently FireFox), that means you need script to trigger click on the select when clicking on the fake drop down. However if customizing you should change the whole `select` (don't use it) with other element (such as a `div`). The best choice here is you should use some UI library like jQuery UI, it has some widgets for you.

Comment: it's acceptable that if the drop-down does not work (when `pointer-events:none` is not supported), user can still uses the select by clicking on other regions such as right at the center of the select.